# How to use canvas-confetti package in react

Tags: reactjs, canvas

I was trying to implement a confetti animation on a canvas in react using the canvas-confetti package. But I keep getting the following error

[image]

my code looks like this

```
import confetti from "canvas-confetti";

const canvas = document.querySelector(".confetti");
  try {
    const myConfetti = confetti.create(canvas, {
      resize: true,
      useWorker: true,
    });

    myConfetti({
      particleCount: 100,
      spread: 160,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  return (
    <div className="counter">
      <canvas className="confetti" />
    </div>
  );
```